# Rewrite a pay computation with time-and-a-half for overtime and create a function called computepay which takes two parameters(hours and rate0

Tags: python, function, parameters

Here is my code (btw I am new to Stackoverflow and coding in general so forgive me if I made some mistakes in formatting this question):

```
hours = int(input('Enter hours:'))
rate =  int(input('Enter rate:'))
pay =('Your pay this month' + str((hours + hours/2) * rate))
def computepay(hours,rate):
pay =('Your pay this month' + str((hours + hours/2) * rate))
return pay 

print(pay)
```

Comment: 1) Are the first 3 lines trying to compute pay without a function and the following lines trying to convert those lines to a function?  2) Shouldn't there be a different rate for overtime, 3) After how many hours of regular pay do you start getting the overtime rate? 4) lines in a function should be indented from the function declaration line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take into account overtime versus regular rates of pay it seems like you will need to know how much time the employee worked in each category.  With that in mind, here is a simplified example to illustrate some of the key concepts.

Example:

```
def computepay(hours, rate):
    return hours * rate

regular_rate = float(input("Hourly rate in dollars: "))
regular_hours = float(input("Regular hours worked: "))
overtime_hours = float(input("Overtime hours worked: "))

regular_pay = computepay(regular_hours, regular_rate)
overtime_pay = computepay(overtime_hours, regular_rate * 1.5)
total_pay = regular_pay + overtime_pay

print(f"This pay period you earned: ${total_pay:.2f}")
```

Output:

```
Hourly rate in dollars:  15.00
Regular hours worked:  40
Overtime hours worked:  10
This pay period you earned: $825.00
```

Answer (score 0):

My teacher told me to solve it in one function, **computerpay** . so try this .

```
def computepay(hours, rate):
if hours > 40:
    reg = rate * hours
    otp = (hours - 40.0) * (rate * 0.5)
    pay = reg + otp
else:
    pay = hours * rate 
return pay
```

Then The input Output Part

```
sh = input("enter Hours:")
sr = input(" Enter rate:")
fh = float(sh)
fr = float(sr)
xp = computepay(fh,fr)
print("Pay:",xp)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def computepay(hours, rate) :
   return hours * rate
def invalid_input() :
   print("Input Numeric Value")
while True :
   try :
      regular_rate = float(input("Hourly rate in dollars: "))
      break
   except :
      invalid_input()
      continue
while True :
   try :
      regular_hours = float(input("Regular Hours Worked: "))
      break
   except :
      invalid_input()
      continue
while True :
   try :
      overtime_hours = float(input("Overtime hours worked :"))
      break
   except :
      invalid_input()
      continue
overtime_rate = regular_rate * 1.5

regular_pay = computepay(regular_hours, regular_rate)
overtime_pay = computepay(overtime_hours, overtime_rate)
total_pay = regular_pay + overtime_pay

print("PAY : ", total_pay)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def computepay(hours, rate):
    if (hours <= 40.0):
        pay = hours * rate
    else:
        pay = (40.0 * rate) + (1.5 * (hours - 40.0) * rate)
    return pay


try:
    hours = float(input('Enter Hours: '))
    rate = float(input("Enter rate: "))
    pay = computepay(hours, rate)
    print('Pay: ', pay)

except:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your answer to include a description of what your code does.

Answer (score -1):

## This code calculates the regular wage with flat rates and overtime with time-and-half for any work hours over forty(40) hours per work week.

```
hour = float(input('Enter hours: '))

rate = float(input('Enter rates: '))


def compute_pay(hours, rates):

if hours <= 40:

    print(hours * rates)

elif hours > 40:

    print(((hours * rate) - 40 * rate) * 1.5 + 40 * rate)



compute_pay(hour, rate )
```

Comment: Code-only answer are discouraged. Please consider adding some explanation to your code, and, particularly, since this is an old question with old upvoted answers, explanation on why your answer is different, and even better, than the already existing answers.

Answer (score -2):

## This code calculates the regular wage with flat rates and overtime with time-and-half for any work hours over forty(40) hours per work week.

```
hour = float(input('Enter hours: '))
rate = float(input('Enter rates: '))

def compute_pay(hours, rates):

    if hours <= 40:
        pay = hours * rates
        return pay
    elif hours > 40:
        pay = ((hours * rate) - 40 * rate) * 1.5 + 40 * rate
        return pay

pay = compute_pay(hour, rate)
print(pay)
```